# Windows 10 Quick Search not Showing Results from 2nd Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, search, windows-search

I have a machine running Win10 anniversary, with an SSD mounted at C, and a HD mounted at D. Both drives are NTFS-formatted, and have indexing enabled.

Searching from Windows Explorer works for both drives, but searching from the Start menu only yields results from C, not D.

I've tried disabling/re-enabling indexing on both drives, and rebuilding the index to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. Make sure the programs that are on your second drive are in here. If your shortcuts inside the folders listed there do not have an image, it seems to be a problem with ownership.

Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows` and right click "Start Menu" -> Properties -> Security tab -> Advanced.

At the "Owner:" field click Change and type in Everyone and click "Check Names". Everyone should be listed there and click "Ok". Check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects". Now click on "Everyone" in the list of "Permission entries:" and click on "Edit" and give full permissions.

After that make sure you check "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" and click "Apply". Your shortcut icons inside the Programs folder will  return and Windows can find all your applications again. I do not know what broke this in the first place. This is how I fixed it on my end.